# Rails 3.1 autoload issue with Erector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, erector

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Views::Setup::User):
  app/views/setup/user.html.rb:1:in `_app_views_setup_user_html_rb___557294190_11042'
  actionpack (3.1.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `render'
  activesupport (3.1.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.1.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
  actionpack (3.1.12) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.1.12) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.1.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.1.12) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.1.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
  ...

parameters: {"controller"=>"setup", "action"=>"user"}
```

It appears as though, when running in development mode, the first pageload of a given page will succeed, then the second pageload will throw this uninitialized constant error, referencing the file where the constant (class) is defined...

Was working fine before in Rails 3.0.

- Rails 3.1.12
- JRuby 1.7.11
- Erector 0.10.0

Comment: Check your `render` and `redirect_to` calls. without seeing the controller I can only guess but that would be my first assumption as to where the error was.

Comment: Hm, along those lines it could be related to using the `inherited_resources` gem (I'm not directly calling render). Doesn't seem to be any bugs filed along those lines though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to have been an issue between Rails 3.1 and the Erector gem.

For some reason or another, views named in the scheme "view_name.html.rb" aren't loaded properly after the first load. The same file named "view_name.rb" works fine.

This appears to no longer be the case upon bumping to Rails 3.2, so I assume it's a quirk in 3.1 not properly checking mime types when autoloading.